# Spring Webflux(reactive) handler function Server Request not reading file data uploaded from Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to read the file uploaded from postman in spring boot webflux project. The end point is handled through handler function.

Below is the code.

Route Configuration

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(CsvHandler csvHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(
                RequestPredicates.path("/upload").and(RequestPredicates.method(HttpMethod.POST))
                        .and(RequestPredicates.contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)),
                        csvHandler::formsubmit);
}
```

Handler Code:

```
 public Mono<ServerResponse> formsubmit(ServerRequest serverRequest){
            serverRequest.body(BodyExtractors.toMultipartData())
            .filter(map->map.size()>0)
            .map(map->{
                Map<String, Part> singleValuedMap=map.toSingleValueMap();
                singleValuedMap.forEach((key,value)->{
                    System.out.println(key);
                    System.out.println(value);
                });
                return map.toString();
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty());
            return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue("check");
    }
```

Postman req:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/upload' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'file=@"/C:/Users/anubhavnigam01/Downloads/DOC-20230704-WA0003..pdf"'
```

Serverrequest in the above code is not reading the multipart data.

Comment: Could someone please comment on this ..